# How to upgrade laravel 5.4 project to laravel 9?

Tags: laravel-8

How to upgrade the laravel old version to latest.
My old project is in php5.6 and laravel 5.4 . I opened the project folder in vs code with latest version of PHP and laravel I want to make changes in the project of that old version will it be done? What will be the steps

Comment: Anything not working if you apply the upgrade notes?

Comment: Open laravel docs with upgrade guide and upgrade version to version - 5.8,6,7,8,9.